Convert polygon geometry to renderable hair with Geometry Nodes
How can I convert this regular mesh (polygonal) to renderable hairs using just geometry nodes?


I think is not possible. The object type should be Curves to make it renderable as hair. Otherwise, it will not visible on render. You can only add depth to this mesh, to make it renderable.

You can turn the mesh into a set of splines (a curve object), then turn it back to a renderable mesh.
Play with the divide and radius values to set the radial appearence of the hair.


Yeah but then I can't use the Hair BSDF. I'm asking this because I'm importing a simulated hair alembic from Houdini and it comes as a polygonal mesh...
